# Issue with database connection string using Helm and kubernetes secrets

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I'm trying to put a formatted Postgres connection string inside a Kubernetes secret.
I'm using Helm to deploy the apps to the AKS cluster and after the deployment, looking at the values of the secrets in the Azure portal, I see something strange.

The connection string inside the `secrets.yaml` is declared in the following way:

`DatabaseConnectionString: "{{ (printf "Server=%s;Port=%s;Database=%s;User Id=%s;Password=%s" .Values.database.host .Values.database.port .Values.database.name .Values.database.user .Values.database.password) | b64enc }}"`

Looking at the value in the Azure portal, I have the following result:

`Server=****;Port=%!s(int64=5432);Database=postgres;User Id=***;Password=***`

the value for `Port` has a strange value, while the others are correct.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the format string, use `%d` for the (integer) port number.

```yaml
{{ with .Values.database }}
DatabaseConnectionString: "{{ printf "Server=%s;Port=%d;..." .host .port | b64enc }}"
{{ end }}
```

This comes from the [Go `fmt` package](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt).  The `!%s(int64=...)` is its way of reporting an error: `%s` specifically expects a string but it got an integer value instead.

You may also be able to use `%v` everywhere in the string to get a default format for both strings and numbers.  (Note that the format won't be usable as YAML for lists and maps, though.)

Comment: That solved the problem. I didn't realize that I was using `%s` for an integer